# How to get a record from database and populate textbox on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, api, asp.net-mvc-5

First of all sorry for my bad english.
I'm new to using AJAX and API's so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I have to populate some text boxes after the selection of a dropdown list,let's say I have to use: Name  Last_Name  Age  Gender

I already had coded an ajax function and an API which works fine(I'm using it on another view for display purposes) however my ajax code is not working, it does not fill the textbox as it's supposed to do.
I tried to troubleshot the request using Chrome, this is the url:

https://localhost:44397/api/pacient/21?id=21&_=1510262500793

According to me, this url shoud contain the name of my database record, however I got two times my pacient id.

My dropdown list:

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pacient)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Pacient, new SelectList(Model.Pacient,"Id", "Name"), "--Select--", new { id = "pacientSelector", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

My API Controller Action(Using Automapper):

```
    //GET /Api/pacient/1
    public IHttpActionResult GetPacient(int id)
    {
        var pacient = _context.Pacient.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        if (pacient == null)
            return NotFound();


        return Ok(Mapper.Map<Pacient, PacientDto>(pacient));
    }
```

My AJAX function:

```
        $('#pacientSelector').change(function() {
            var pacientId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/pacient/' + pacientId,
                type: 'GET',
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                data: {id: pacientId},
                success: function(data, pacient) {
                    $("#textboxId").val = pacient.Name;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Remove the `+ pacientId` from the `url:` (your already sending it using `data: {id: pacientId},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the id two times, one as querystring in the url (*by explicitly concatenating the value to the url*)  and one in the `data`. Since you are using **`GET`** as the method, jQuery `$.ajax` method will append the data property value to the url as querystring key value items, hence you are seeing the value 2 times. ***But even though you are sending it twice. Your api action method will be still able to get the value from one of them.***

If the duplicate values in url bother you,simply remove of them.

```
$('#pacientSelector').change(function() {
    var pacientId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/pacient/',              
        data: {id: pacientId}
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Now to set the textbox value, you need to use the `val()` method. Also make sure you are accessing the correct response variable coming back to the `done` or `success` handler.

```
.done(function(data) {
    $("#textboxId").val(data.Name);
});
```

This should work assuming the response object has a `Name` property. Remember, javascript is **case sensitive**. So if your web API is configured to return lowercase, use `data.name`

You can replace the `$.ajax` call with the shorthand `$.get` call to make it more compact

```
$('#pacientSelector').change(function () {

    $.get('/api/pacient/' + $(this).val())
        .done(function (data) {
            $("#textboxId").val(data.Name);
        });
});
```

Comment: I removed one of them as you said.
This fixed the URL, now i get https://localhost:44399/api/pacient/?id=15
I tested the url using Postman tool and it works perfect!! but It stills doesn't fill the textboxt with the "Name" value.Any advice?

Comment: `val` is a method, not a property. See the updated answer.